# Resizing Viewholder in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've got a RecyclerView using the default Linear Layout Manager.

```
llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    ItemListView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Itemlist);
    ItemListView.setLayoutManager(llm);
    final float scale = getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

I am trying to change the height of that one item view to display additional ui elements when the label is clicked.

I tried this with no success

```
vh.itemView.setMinimumHeight((int)(375 *(scale/160)));
```

Can I even change the item height? would I need to implement my own layoutManager?

Comment: The way I did it is hide my additional ui elements from item view initially by calling (some_ui_element).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); and when user taps the item, I unhide the elements by calling(some_ui_element).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); and made sure that the item layout in xml is set to wrap-content for its layout-height. The item cardview (or listview) got resized to show the ui elements. Have you tried this way?

Comment: That worked with one wrinkle I had to set the initial visibility to gone so there was not empty space.

Comment: correct - i meant View.GONE - I posted it as the answer - thanks

Comment: The problem I experience with this approach is that I have to double tap a view to get it to work.  Did anyone else see this and resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hide additional ui elements from item view initially by calling

```
(some_ui_element).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

On item click, unhide the elements by calling

```
   (some_ui_element).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and make sure that the item layout in xml is set to wrap-content for its layout-height. The item cardview (or listview) got resized to show the ui elements.